# typeMismatch custom message never shows

Tags: spring, validation

I am working on a Spring+Hibernate project, I am using validation for my forms and I have ValidationMessages.properties file on classpath it works as I expected except for Date fields, **for Date fields the validations always shows the message**:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date for property fechaFinal; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Column
>   @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.util.Date for value ';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

I was searching to change this and I found I have to use typeMismatch but it does not works for me, no matter how I tried, here are my source:

ValidationMessages.properties

```
typeMismatch = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA
typeMismatch.java.util.Date = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA
typeMismatch.ciclo.fechaInicial = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA 
typeMismatch.ciclo.fechaFinal = La fecha debe tenerel formato DD/MM/AAAA
typeMismatch.Ciclos.fechaInicial = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA 
typeMismatch.Ciclos.fechaFinal = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA
typeMismatch.fechaInicial = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA 
typeMismatch.fechaFinal = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA

string.empty=Este campo es obligatorioo
string.invalid.size=Este campo debe tener una longitud de {min} a {max} caracteres

date.invalid=Fecha obligatoria en formato: DD/MM/AAAA
```

The string.empty and string.invalid.size works fine everytime, the typeMismatch never works..

Entity code Ciclos.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ciclos")  
public class Ciclos implements Serializable{

    //...

    @Column(name = "nombre")    
    @NotEmpty(message="{string.empty}")
    @Size(min=5, max=55, message="{string.invalid.size}")   
    private String nombre;      

    @Column(name = "fecha_inicial")     
    @NotNull    
    private Date fechaInicial;      

    @Column(name = "fecha_final")
    @NotNull(message="{date.invalid}")  
    private Date fechaFinal;

    //... 
}
```

Controller code CiclosController.java

```
@Controller public class CiclosController {

    //...   
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveciclo.html")
    public ModelAndView saveCiclo(@Valid Ciclos ciclo, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelMap){         
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            modelMap.put(BindingResult.class.getName()+".ciclo",bindingResult);         
        }       
        return new ModelAndView("cicloEdit","ciclo",ciclo);
    }    
}
```

View code cicloEdit.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <!-- header data --> 
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some things -->
    <form:form action="saveciclo.html" method="post" commandName="ciclo">
        <form:label path="nombre">Ciclo: </form:label> 
        <form:input path="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del ciclo"></form:input> 
        <form:errors path="nombre"/> <br /> 
        <form:label path="fechaInicial">Inicia en: </form:label>
        <form:input path="fechaInicial" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA fecha de inicio de ciclo">            </form:input>
        <form:errors path="fechaInicial"/> <br />
        <form:label path="fechaFinal">Termina en: </form:label>
        <form:input path="fechaFinal" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA fecha de fin de ciclo"></form:input>
        <form:errors path="fechaFinal"/> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
    </form:form>
</body>
```

So, was wrong with my code?

**Update 10-26-2016 for answer a comment made by nowszy94**

To solve I did:

The file messages, located in location:

```
src/main/resources/messages/messages.properties
```

and its content (related to this issue):

```
typeMismatch.fechaInicial = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA 
typeMismatch.fechaFinal = La fecha debe tener el formato DD/MM/AAAA
fecha.empty = Debe indicar una fecha
fecha.anterior = La fecha debe ser anterior
fecha.invalid = Fecha obligatoria en formato: DD/MM/AAAA
```

As I remember, the order of every error message matters.

Now for configuration, in your aplication context xml file config this bean:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages/messages" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find what was happen. I have a binder in my controller to format Date values, searching and reading a lot of sites I found when a validation occurs, spring before calls binding, and on the binding is when the conversion error happen, so it never take the message for validations.

The solution, add another messages file and configure as default source of messages, so its messages works on binding and validations, now all messages works fine.

Comment: I know it might be a little bit late, but could you please provide code example of that solution?

Comment: Sure, in fact I left this project due to administrative issues, so I forgot details of this code, anyway checking it again, I find the code in a state in which the issue for this question was solved, check the update in original question please, I hope this will be helpful.