# How to validate path variable type: error 400 with wrong parameter and no logs in server, no error message

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/v2/tw/{id}")
public TwDto getTw(Authentication auth, @PathVariable Long id) {
}
```

When I want to fetch data with Postman with wrong parameter type `/v2/tw/variableNoNumber`, then I want to have some logs in service, I want to get some validation error. How to do that?

Should I add eg. `@NumberFormat`? It doesn't work.

I use `@ControllerAdvice`, my project is quite old, everything is validated properly but THIS case is weird for me....

Comment: Maybe you should get `id` parameter as an object and then in your code check validation.

Comment: @navand hmmm maybe that's the solution! Then I can throw any Excption that will be catched in ControllerAdvice

Comment: But I don't remeber if I used Object parameter type instead of Long/Integer... maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: Time has passed, and maybe something has changed recently, but AFAIK you can't validate a type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072595/spring-mvc-custom-validation-message-for-typemismatch

Comment: When you pass a String for `id` you would get `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` and nested exception as `java.lang.NumberFormatException` then go to the ControllerAdvice and add an ExceptionHandler for `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` exception type and throw any custom exception that you want to.

Comment: "I want to get some validation error" - get where? you want to return error page? log it? write it into file? or?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate Spring MVC @PathVariable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values)

Comment: I have to send error message to the client -  currently when invoking endpoint by Postman I receive 400 error without any response body... In spring boot server NO logs

Comment: @Matley did you try what I suggested? In your ExceptionHandler method you can also log the error if you want something on the logs.

Comment: @Sudoss yeas I tried your soution but surprisingly no MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException was thrown...

Comment: Do you already have an ExceptionHandler catching `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` ? If yes, put a debug point there and see the control would go there.

Comment: Yes, and in debug mode I'm not going to ControllerAdvice exception handler MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException...

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom exception handler.

- This is your custom entity.

```java
public class ApiException {
    private final String message;
    private final HttpStatus httpStatus;
 

    public ApiException(String message, HttpStatus httpStatus ) {
        this.message = message;
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }


    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
    }

    
}
```

- This is your exception class.

```java
public class ApiRequestException extends RuntimeException {

    public ApiRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ApiRequestException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

- And finally ApiExceptionHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ApiRequestException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiRequestException(ApiRequestException e) {
        HttpStatus badRequest = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        ApiException apiException = new ApiException(e.getMessage(), badRequest));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, badRequest);
    }
}
```

For example, if you want to validate the ID you can write as below.

```java
throw new ApiRequestException("Case by id" + TwDto.getId+ " was not found!");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found solution for my problem - instead of throwing 400 with some message maybe it would be sufficient to add:

```
@GetMapping("/v2/tw/{id:\d+}")
public TwDto getTw(Authentication auth, @PathVariable Long id) {
}
```

Then I get `404 error Not found` and I think this approach is better than returning 400 error without any message... What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the annotation @Valid for the parameter and handle the exception with the ConstraintViolationException. For more information and detail see here:
https://medium.com/@aamine/customized-input-validation-in-spring-boot-1927aa440bc6

Comment: I'm afraid I have PathVariable, not RequestParam... Valid doesnt work, I still receive only 400 error without any logs, without any message