# How to get only nested exception message form spring validation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, numberformatexception

Context

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <org.springframework.boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>8.0.15</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <org.apache.tomcat.embed.version>9.0.12</org.apache.tomcat.embed.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.13.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <javax.el.version>3.0.0</javax.el.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I've prepared `BigDecimalEditor` class, that extends `PropertyEditorSupport` and it works OK - it throws `NumberFormatException` from overridden `setAsText(String text)` method.
Next I've prepared `CustomBindingErrorProcessor`, that extends `DefaultBindingErrorProcessor` where the method `processPropertyAccessException(PropertyAccessException accessException, BindingResult bindingResult)` is overridden as follows:

```
   public void processPropertyAccessException(PropertyAccessException accessException, 
                                           BindingResult bindingResult) {

    // overwrites NumberFormatException error message
    if(accessException.getCause() instanceof NumberFormatException){

        String fieldName = accessException.getPropertyChangeEvent().getPropertyName();
        String exceptionError = accessException.getCause().getMessage();

        FieldError fieldError = new FieldError(fieldName,
                                               "BINDING_ERROR", 
                                               fieldName + ": " + exceptionError);

        bindingResult.addError(fieldError);
    }else{
        super.processPropertyAccessException(accessException, bindingResult);
    }

}
```

and still it displays (near validated form field) such a very long message:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.math.BigDecimal for property height; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: The Number not recognized!

if text contains two commas for example.

The question is - how to get to the message of the nested exception only "The Number not recognized!"

Answer (score 1):

here a link that speak about it [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072595/spring-mvc-custom-validation-message-for-typemismatch)

i was able to resolve it, since the messages.properties adding:
typeMismatch.object.camp=something wrong

Comment: Thank You - it works! Only simple entries in the file: <projectPath>/src/main/resources/messages.properties " 
typeMismatch.weight=Ops! Something's wrong with weight!
typeMismatch.height=Ops! Something's wrong with height!
typeMismatch.age=Ops! Something's wrong with age!
"
- or even - 
"
typeMismatch.java.math.BigDecimal=Number not recognized!!!
"
Seems so simple now. Unbelievable ;)